# Search character B in a row. Recursion

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function. It works with the help of the loop. How to rewrite it recursively?

```
function countBs(str) {
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
    if ( str.charAt(i) == 'B' )
      counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}
```

Comment: You have to try. I'd start by looking at my problem and dividing into repeatable smaller problem with a base case that stops the recursion.

Comment: I obtained only with nested functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My effort

```
function countBs(str, mychar) {
  if (str !== '') {
    if (str.substring(0, 1) === mychar) {
      return 1 + countBs(str.substring(1), mychar);
    } else {
      return 0 + countBs(str.substring(1), mychar);
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

I added the parameter char, so that you can specify any character you want.

```
countBs('BBBBBsss', 'B');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countBs(str){
  if(str == ""){
    return 0;
  }else{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    if(str.charAt(str.length-1) == 'b'){
      return countBs(str.substring(0, str.length-1)) + 1;
    }else{
      return countBs(str.substring(0, str.length-1));
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to only check for upper-case B's you can obviously leave out the `str.toLowerCase()` and just compare to `B`. This function counts both upper and lower-case B's in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the counter as a function too

```
function countBs(str, counter, index) 
{
  //initialize values if not passed
  counter = counter && counter > str.length || 0;
  index = index  && index > str.length || 0;

  //terminating condition  
  if ( index  == str.length )
  {
      return counter;
  }  

  if ( str.charAt(index++) == 'B' )
  {
      counter++;
  }

  return countBs(str, counter, index);
}
```

Now invoke the method as

```
countBs( "asdasds23dbdssd" );
```